# execute unix commands inside hive script

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am writing hive script and I need to read a file in hdfs inside hive script and use the file content in hive query. The file in hdfs contains date in single line.

I know we can use unix commands in hive shell by using '`!`'  But I need to use the below command and it is not working with !

```
while IFS= read -r line; do snapshot_id=$line done < <(hadoop fs -cat /hdfs_path/date.txt)

select * from <tablename> where datestring = $snapshot_id
```

Is it possible. ?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what you need,

```
#!/bin/bash

old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(hadoop fs -cat /hdfs_path/date.txt)
do
   hive -f "select * from test where datestring = $line"
done          
IFS=$old_IFS
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I dont want shell script. I need hql script that I will be executing it from oozie

Comment: why can't you run as shell action instead of hive action in oozie

Comment: Why not both? You should be able to pass an argument from the shell action to a hive action